# Rendered <p:panel> content by click on expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, frontend

Currently I have a developed frontend with JSF which loads too much data and this is not in all cases needed by the user, this mentioned data is divided by tags , i need that information rendered dynamically by click on expand panel:

```
        <p:panel header="#{myBean.someStringTittle}"
            id="information1" toggleable="true" rendered="true" collapsed="true">

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText
                            value="#{mybean.someVale]}" />
                        <p:inputText readonly="true">
                                ......
                                ......
        <p:panel>
```

In many cases the user doesn’t need to see the information inside that panel, the property collapsed="true" load the panel closed, but the information inside the panel has rendered, i need that information to render only if the user expand the panel.

How could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean it still renders `<h:panelGrid>` without clicking on `<p:panel>`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try write a event handlers for the 'tabChange' and/or 'tabClose' events. Based on which tab was activated, dynamically load the content into a backing bean. And then when the web page refreshes, it would display the content.

This is the "Change Event" example of the Primefaces show case for accordion panel.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it either with a [p:accordionPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml) with just one tab:

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part I">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />
            <h:outputText
                value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

or put a `p:ajax` on the existing [panel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panel.xhtml)

```
<p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{myBean.onToggle}" update="information1" />
```

with

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{myBean.boole}">
```

and set boole to true in onToggle().